# Binomial Distribution vs. Profit

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose I have 20 coins. Each time I am allowed to place a bet between 1 and 20 coins. Each time I placed a bet of 1 coin on the item I have 5% chance of getting the item. That means if I place 20 coins into the bet I have 100% chance of getting the item. The number of betting round is unlimited (of course I have 20 coins so I am only allowed to bet 20 times at max)

What should be the betting tatic to maximise the chance of winning the item using fewest coins possible? I can certainly caculate that if I continue placing 1 coins each then the probability of wining the item is 64%, but a strategy like placing 10 times of 2 coins at once resulting in the winning probability of 65%. Or we can even think of using a mixed bet strategy, say betting 10 coins then 5 coins.

Edit 1: I should have written the question in the following way: What is the best ratio of winning chance versus the number of coin spent?

Comment: Either you can ask "how can I minimize the number of coin bets I have to place to guarantee x probability of winning in a certain number of rounds?" or you can ask "how can I maximize my probability of winning given I only want to place x coin bets?" but to optimize both at once is impossible without some more restraints

Comment: What does it mean to maximize the chance of winning using the fewest coins possible?  You can win all the time by betting $20$ coins, as you said.  No other strategy will result in $100\%$ success.  Why is this not the optimal strategy?

Comment: You can place a bet of zero in some rounds, right? And can you bet partial coins?

Comment: paulinho has clairified the question, I should have written in his way: maximizing the ratio of the winning chance to the number of coins spent. Of course I can place all the coin in one bet and get the item, however I was wondering if there is a better ratio of the wining chance versus the number of coin spent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to maximize the ratio of the winning chance to the number of coins spent. Assuming you can only bet a whole number of coins each round, it is always best to bet only in one round. Why?

Let's first outline a basic arithmetic fact:

**Lemma:** For any positive numbers $p_1, \cdots, p_n \leq q$ subject to $\sum_{i = 1}^n p_i = q$, 
$$\prod_{i = 1}^n (1 - p_i) \geq 1 -q $$
**Proof:** The proof follows immediately from the fact that for any positive numbers $x, y$, 
$$(1 - x)(1-y) \geq 1 - x - y$$
To prove it for any number $n$ of terms, one can apply this inequality $n - 1$ times to achieve the final result. $\square$

Let's first consider the case where you are betting all of your $20$ coins across some rounds. In this case, it's clear that the best strategy is to bet them all on one round - otherwise, you would have spent the same amount and risked a non-zero chance of not winning the prize. So if we're forced to bet $20$ coins, we should bet them all in one round.

Let's generalize this to a case where we are forced to bet $c$ coins, where $1 \leq c \leq 20$. Let's normalize the coin values so you have $1$ unit of currency total (for example, each coin could be a nickel, for those in the United States, in which case we have a dollar total). Then we seek to minimize the chance of failure $f$, where 
$$f = \prod_{i = 1}^{20} (1 - p_i)$$
subject to the constraint $\sum_{i = 1}^{20} p_i = 0.05 \cdot c$. Our chance of winning is then $1 - f$. But we established before that the expression for $f$ is at least $1 - 0.05 \cdot c$, which is obtained when we bet all $c$ coins in one round. Therefore, our best chance of winning given that we bet $c$ coins total across the rounds is $0.05 \cdot c$. So for example, if you were forced to spend $19$ coins, then your maximum chance of winning would be $0.95$, obtained by betting all coins in one round.

It now remains to calculate the ratio of winning chance to the number of coins spent, for all possible values of $c$ we can spend. This ratio is
$$r = \frac{0.05 \cdot c}{c} = 0.05$$
so it is constant for whichever value of $c$ we choose! A quick check shows that this is indeed true (try choosing arbitrary values of $c$ for yourself).

Thus, there is no *single* best strategy, but there are a set of best strategies, which are given by betting $c$ coins in one round, with $1 \leq c \leq 20$, and not betting in any other round.

Note that this answer crucially depends on the modelling assumption that you want to maximize the winning chance to the number of coins spent. If this is not so, then you may wish to clarify that in the question. But this is the only non-trivial reading of the question I understood: for example, if you wished to maximize the ratio of the number of expected prizes to number of coins spent, then any strategy is as good as any other.

Comment: Yes that assumption is very correct to my thinking, just that I could not find a way to express that in the question. Many thanks for the very detailed answer.